# Lazy function arguments?

Tags: scala

How to make "areYouLazy" function evaluate "string" only once the best possible way?

```
def areYouLazy(string: => String) = {
    string
    string
  }

areYouLazy {
  println("Generating a string")
  "string"
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because your `string` is not a variable.

Comment: You can assign it to a variable in `areYouLazy`, like `val notLazyAnymore = string; string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Call-by-name* arguments are executed everytime you access them.

To avoid multiple executions, you can simply use a `lazy` cache value that is executed only the first time it is accessed:

```
def areYouLazy(string: => String) = {
  lazy val cache = string
  cache  // executed
  cache  // simply access the stored value
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

I ended up doing it through a function. Seems more readable. Less names to give to variables.

`private def putOnTable(getCard: () => Option[Card])(implicit table: Table) = getCard() match {
    case cardOption @ Some(card) =>
      table.addCard(card)

      cardOption
    case None =>
      None
  }`

Comment: @HappyCoder - I don't understand why you think `getCard` isn't an extra name.  Also, it's harder to pass an argument to `() => A` than to `=> A`.  There might be reasons to do it your way, but "more readable" and "fewer names" aren't among them.